# Change the status bar background color color past iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistatusbar

I want to change background color of status bar on iOS 7, and I'm using this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

        self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);

        ...
        ...


}
```

When I write this it shows the status bar with a black background; I want it to have a red background.

[image]

How can change the color of the status bar to have a red background instead of black?

Comment: You add subview of red color.    read this once https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html

Comment: There is no way to change color of status Bar ? other then adding subview.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In iOS 7 and later, the status bar is **transparent**. Set the `backgroundColor` of your view to the color you want for the status bar.

Or, you can add a 20px-high subview with red color at the top of your view.

See the [Apple Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1) for more.

Also, make sure that your `preferredStatusBarStyle` is `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`. and in your Info.plist set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO".

Comment: preferredStatusBarStyle is already `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and i cannot change background color to red because i want bg with white and only status bar with red. there is no way to change color of `status Bar` ? other then adding subview.

Comment: No then you have to add Subview of frame CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,20.0).

Comment: Putting this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate fixed my issue.

Answer (score 27):

While handling the background color of status bar in iOS 7, there are 2 cases

Case 1: View with Navigation Bar

In this case use the following code in your viewDidLoad method

```
  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  CGFloat statusBarHeight = app.statusBarFrame.size.height;

  UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -statusBarHeight, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, statusBarHeight)];
  statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Case 2: View without Navigation Bar

In this case use the following code in your viewDidLoad method

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 CGFloat statusBarHeight = app.statusBarFrame.size.height;

 UIView *statusBarView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, statusBarHeight)];
 statusBarView.backgroundColor  =  [UIColor yellowColor];
 [self.view addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Comment: This is perfect for the use-case where the viewcontroller has NOT been embedded in a navigation controller.

This is the swift equivalent:

    `let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`
    `let overlayFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: statusBarHeight)`
    `self.statusBarOverlayView = UIView(frame: overlayFrame)`
    `self.statusBarOverlayView.barTintColor = UIColor.green`
    `self.view.addSubview(self.statusBarOverlayView)`

Answer (score 8):

Objective c

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:false];
    UIView *statusBar=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
    statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];



    return YES;
}
```

This is working for me. I hope this will help you too.

Comment: There is an issue with this solution, when you double press the home button, this status status bar color will disappear. like the question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250495/a-issue-on-changing-the-color-of-the-status-bar-when-switching-apps-on-iphone)

Answer (score 5):

for what @Teja Kumar Bethina  provided is helpful, but it's better to get the height of the statusBar from UIApplication singleton like below:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -app.statusBarFrame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, app.statusBarFrame.size.height)];
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: I agree. Hard coded values must be avoided. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

in AppDelegate use

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

and in project info.plist file

set flag NO to View controller-based status bar appearance in app.

Comment: It changes only text color of status bar and not the background color

Comment: It will automatically update as per Navigation bar color. Do you want different from navigation bar?

Answer (score 3):

Call this function from ViewDidLoad passing with your status bar color.

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor)  
{
    guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView 
    else 
    {
    return
    }
    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Hope It'll help.

Comment: The typecast in swift 3 syntax: `let statusBar = (UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a swift solution that uses auto layout, If your application is in portrait or landscape the bar will be the correct width. It's added to the navigation bar view as a subview hence it's offset by -20. You could add it to your navigationbar's parent view, and then the offset is not required. This example will also set the colour to be the same as the navigation bar.

Hope that helps :)

```
    // Add colored opaque view behind the status bar view
    let statusBarView = UIView()
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = navigationBar.backgroundColor
    statusBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    navigationBar.addSubview(statusBarView)

    let views = ["statusBarView": statusBarView]
    let hConstraint = "H:|-0-[statusBarView]-0-|"
    let vConstraint = "V:|-(-20)-[statusBarView(20)]"

    var allConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(hConstraint,
            options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    allConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(vConstraint,
            options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)
```

Answer (score -4):

if your application is navigation based then you can set status bar background color red like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

may it will help.

Comment: this code doesn't work for me :( ,As u can see there is no `UINavigationBar` only status bar is there