# Custom background color for status bar in iOS app created with Xcode and Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, statusbar, uistatusbar

I already googled a little bit but without success.
I want to have a custom background color for the status bar in all my ViewControllers (only in portrait mode). The ViewControllers are managed with a TabBarController.

Does anybody know how to do that? Maybe anybody has a code sample?

Comment: refer this link it may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180173/unable-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-color-on-ios-7

Comment: Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662704/custom-background-color-for-status-bar-in-ios-app-written-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved the problem myself by putting a UIView below the Status bar and set the background color. But I had to clear all constraints and add them again to make the UIView hiding in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help.

```
let demoView = UIView()
demoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 22)
demoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(demoView)
```

Comment: I put it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.swift, right?

Comment: I get: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'view'. What does it mean?

Comment: Put it inside the viewDidLoad () of your view controller.

Comment: This it what I'm getting: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160606/wm3f9vmo.jpg
Something seems to be wrong.

Comment: Instead of 320 use self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: It's working now but it shows it in landscape, too. Do you know a better/other solution?