# Change Background Color Status Bar iOS

Tags: swift, uistatusbar

So, I'm trying to make this:

[image]

i tried using UIView in back of Status bar and set the color to orange, but when running, The UIView displayed right under the status bar, so it's still White

i'm trying many solution in the internet but none of them work. Yes it works but when i move to other view controller and back again, The color dissapeared. What should I do? i'm using swift

Comment: Can you add a code example of what you are running? Also which version of swift and ios are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7

Comment: You have to make your UIView in fullscreen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180173/unable-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-color-on-ios-7

Comment: thanks @luiyezheng that works for me :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true

let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView

statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
```

Try using this code in your appDelegate's method **application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

Comment: There is an issue with this solution, when you double press the home button, this status status bar color will disappear. like the question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250495/a-issue-on-changing-the-color-of-the-status-bar-when-switching-apps-on-iphone)