# A issue on Changing the Color of the Status Bar when switching apps on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar

I want to change the Status Bar color with the specific view controller.

According to StackOverFlow's answers , i achieved it.

There is **an issue** , when switching apps on iPhone, the color I have set fades, goes back to initial state.

**It's OK.** Please notice the status bar.

[image]

**Not OK.**  Please notice the status bar.

[image]
I can't figure it out. The code I tried:

1. set `statusBar.backgroundColor`,

   ```
   UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
   if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];
   }
   ```

**2.** insert subview to  statusBar.

```
 UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
 UIView * backgroundColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 20) ];
 backgroundColorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
 backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];
 [statusBar.subviews.firstObject insertSubview: backgroundColorView atIndex:0];
```

**3.**  So is to insert layer(CALayer).

And I tried to analyze it with breakpoints.

**-** When the app is a active, and double-click the Home button to Switch apps, the method is not called  `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` . It confuses me a little .

**-** I try to change the background color of status bar in the Application's method `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`,  It doesn't work. I don't know why.

While from Github's source code, **It's OK through Runtime**. My company don't like using **Runtime**.

Is there some other way **without runtime** ?

And I don't know how runtime interacts with  iPhone's switching apps mode.

The main question is to solve it **without runtime**. More explain is welcomed. i think it is easy , what do i miss ?

Many thanks in advances.

Comment: You can't change the status bar color while your app is not active. When you are in the app switcher window, the OS controls the color of the status bar because your app is not the active app on the window. So I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  [This repo](https://github.com/wangrui460/WRNavigationBar) is OK with runtime. And the app *meetup*  did it more complicated too.

Comment: You are right , I adjust the background color of the status bar position by changing the **View**,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for Swift 4:

And it fits the situation of viewControllers managed by navigationViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let statusBarBgView = { () -> UIView in
        let statusBarWindow: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as! UIView
        let statusBarBgView = UIView(frame: (statusBarWindow.statusBar?.bounds)!)
        return statusBarBgView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        self.statusBarBgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        navigationBar?.superview?.insertSubview(self.statusBarBgView, aboveSubview: navigationBar!)
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.statusBarBgView.removeFromSuperview()
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

}

extension UIView {
    var statusBar: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}
```

The Answer Of Objective-C version:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle=UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
    self.statusBarBgView = [[UIView alloc ] initWithFrame: statusBar.bounds ];
    self.statusBarBgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];
    [navigationBar.superview insertSubview: self.statusBarBgView aboveSubview: navigationBar];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.statusBarBgView removeFromSuperview ];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

The status bar which shows the OS infos，is **UIWindow** ,controlled by the OS when  in the app switcher window.

```
UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
```

So it's OK to adjust the background color of **the status bar position** by changing the **View** , when  in the app switcher window.

Comment: Someone write the swift version Please!

Comment: Updated . Hope u like

Comment: Not working when ViewCantroller popover from bottom to top.

Comment: Sure. The ViewController hierarchy is different. My situation is Navigation Push . Perhaps you should ask a new question, and leave a link @TusharLathiya

Answer (score 0):

Modified from previous answer:

```
struct Utility {
    static var statusBarBgView = { () -> UIView in
        let statusBarBgView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
        return statusBarBgView
    }()
}

extension UIViewController {

    func setupStatusBar(statusBarBgView: inout UIView) {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        statusBarBgView.backgroundColor = .red
        let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.insertSubview(statusBarBgView, aboveSubview: navigationBar!)
    }
}

// Usage:
self.setupStatusBar(statusBarBgView: &Utility.statusBarBgView)
```